# Add different images to div elements with same class

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select the div elements with same class using css and apply different css attributes to these div elements.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="image"><br/>a</div>

<div class="image"><br/>b</div>

<div class="image"><br/>c</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.image:before {
   content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
}

//want to show different image for the three divs in html
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/htfhjzbo/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [nth of type selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```css
.image:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><br/>a</div>

<div class="image"><br/>b</div>

<div class="image"><br/>c</div>
```

Comment: works great. can i control the image width and height attributes also. width and height parameters didn't work  http://jsfiddle.net/htfhjzbo/2/

Comment: the reason you can't set width and height is that you're missing `overflow` property http://jsfiddle.net/maio/htfhjzbo/3/

Comment: you are a rockstar. any way to align center that image?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the nth-child pseudoselector `[parent element] .image:nth-child(n)` and you can select them individually based on their position in the array of children with that class name (starting from 1).

As Alaa Mohammead mentioned, you can change the styles inline, but then it requires an `!important` declaration later if the site is responsive, so it's usually not a good practice to get into over simply using a stylesheet to apply the styles you want.